# Automatically Zip/Manage SQL Server 2005 backups

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2005, compression

Is there a nice way to have SQL Server 2005 run nightly backups that are automatically zipped with only the last n backups kept?

I know the agent can perform nightly backups, but I think the tricky part of this question would be the zipping up and removing very old backups

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the SQL backup we run another task to run a batch file to zip the files and copy these onto a NAS. We keep the last 3 backups - the basic script looks something like:

```
d:
cd \MSSQL\BACKUP
zip -rq d:\northwind northwind.BAK
REM - do the local copy to the NAS
move/y \\10.0.0.1\sql_backup\yesterday\northwind.zip \\10.0.0.1\sql_backup\2DaysAgo\northwind.zip
move/y \\10.0.0.1\sql_backup\northwind.zip \\10.0.0.1\sql_backup\yesterday\northwind.zip
copy northwind.zip \\10.0.0.1\sql_backup\northwind.zip
```

(I've edited the script to only show 1 database). At the end of the script we call a Python script to send an email that tells us how big the backup files were and date they were created. You could easily use a WSH script instead. I think that the "if errorlevel..." instruction might have been added because the SQL agent doesn't always detect if the batch file completed or not?

```
if errorlevel 1 goto weakspace
d:\scripts\send_email_nas_copy_success.py
goto end
weakspace:
REM - error occured
d:\scripts\send_email_nas_copy_fail.py
end:
exit
```

One of our servers uses winrar instead of zip to compress the files (it has a command prompt). Once a month last night's backups are copied into an archive that's kept for six months, but you could easily create another batch file to run once a week to maintain backups of last Sunday, 2 Sundays ago and 3 Sundays ago.

Comment: Nice and simple - i like :)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote [automssqlbackup](http://devio.wordpress.com/category/automssqlbackup/) which creates backups, rotates, zips, and sends email. Powershell and free.

Answer (score 1):

There is a software: [SqlBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/). There is a free and a "Premium" version.

The free version includes the "Schedule Backup, Zip" option. Here is a review on a [SQL Authority.com blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/02/sql-server-very-powerful-and-feature-rich-backup-zip-and-ftp-utility-sqlbackupandftp/), which also explains how to use the tool.

---

Alternatively you could call a command line zip (winzip/[wzzip](http://www.winzip.com/prodpagecl.htm)) from the SQL Server extended stored procedure [xp_cmdshell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689(SQL.80).aspx). You could use [robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) the resulting files to a safe place.